# $\mathbb{C}(X)$ as a finite extension of $\mathbb{C}(Y)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, extension-field, rational-functions

Let $X$ and $Y$ affine varieties. If $\mathbb{C}(X)$ (the field of rational functions on $X$) is a finite extension of $\mathbb{C}(Y)$, we can assume that the extension is generated by a single $f\in \mathbb{C}(X)$. However, I read in a proof that we can also assume that $f \in O(X)$, where $O(X)$ is the coordinate ring of $X$. Why is this true?

Comment: Perhaps use the primitive element theorem?

Comment: Yes, what I know is that the primitive element theorem allows us to prove that the extension can be considered as simple. But how does it help with proving that $f$ is a regular function?

Comment: The $f$ furnished by the primitive element need not be regular, but it is a rational function, so you can multiply by the denominator (an element of the smaller field) to obtain a rational function generating the extension.

Comment: If $f$ is multiplied by its denominator, doesn't it become a regular function? Also, why does it still generate the extension?